# Bootable CD for Phoenix BIOS recovery?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

My BIOS got bricked during updating process. On the Internet I found solutions which suggests to create a bootable USB and then hold FN+esc keys etc to restore BIOS but unfortunately neither my USB was set as bootable nor can I see anything on screen since it has gone blank.

How can I restore my BIOS by using a bootable CD to mimic the same procedure?

I have an Acer Aspire 5610z notebook.

Thx

Comment: Have you tried contacting Acer?

Answer (score 1):

If a BIOS is bricked, the manufacturer plans on you not being able to set a bootable device (that is part of the BIOS after all). Chances are, if you hold Fn+esc like they tell you, it will start a special process that will search the USB port for an appropriate boot device and restore the BIOS.

Comment: A usb floppy drive or pen drive usually works, problem is it is different for each manufacturer and bios vendor, different keys to hold and sometimes the bios file has to have a certain name, etc. It does not boot from the drive, it just reads it looking for a certain file name. On HP the file name needs to match the 4 digit motherboard ID number and have a certain extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is the BIOS a removable chip on your motherboard?  If so, this guy has saved my bacon in the past: http://www.badflash.com/

If it's not removable, you still might want to send an email to see if anything can be done about it:

http://www.badflash.com/address.html

[edit]: My apologies, I linked to the wrong site earlier.  Both sites were based in New Jersey and I was posting from memory.